How to pass data from parent to angular material table child component?
I am using angular material table with sorting https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-sorting-example.ts
I plan to use it as a reusable component so that on the parent component, I just need to pass the columns and dataSource like <app-reports-mat-table [columns]="columns" [dataSource]="dataSource"></app-reports-mat-table>
However, only the columns is displayed and the dataSource is undefined on the child component.

If I check that dataSource is set like <app-reports-mat-table *ngIf="dataSource" [columns]="columns" [dataSource]="dataSource"></app-reports-mat-table>, it won't display anything at all.
Please advice how to correctly pass the dataSource to the child component or how can I turn this into reusable component? thank you
Parent template
            <app-reports-mat-table [columns]="columns" [dataSource]="dataSource"></app-reports-mat-table>

Parent ts
export interface FundingNeeds {
  pdoName: string;
  pdoIdentifiedAdvocacy?: string;
  program?: string;
  yearProposed?: string;
  unitOfItem?: string;
  location?: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-report-funding-needs',
  templateUrl: './report-funding-needs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./report-funding-needs.component.css'],
})
export class ReportFundingNeedsComponent {
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<FundingNeeds>;

  columns = [
    {
      columnDef: 'pdoName',
      header: 'PDO Name',
      cell: (element: FundingNeeds) => `${element.pdoName}`,
    },
    {
      columnDef: 'pdoIdentifiedAdvocacy',
      header: 'PDO Identified Advocacy',
      cell: (element: FundingNeeds) => `${element.pdoIdentifiedAdvocacy}`,
    },
    {
      columnDef: 'program',
      header: 'Program',
      cell: (element: FundingNeeds) => `${element.program}`,
    },
    {
      columnDef: 'yearProposed',
      header: 'Year Proposed',
      cell: (element: FundingNeeds) => `${element.yearProposed}`,
    },
    {
      columnDef: 'unitOfItem',
      header: 'Unit of Main Item to Procure/Build',
      cell: (element: FundingNeeds) => `${element.unitOfItem}`,
    },
    {
      columnDef: 'location',
      header: 'Location',
      cell: (element: FundingNeeds) => `${element.location}`,
    },
  ];

  lastEntry = new Date();

  constructor(private reportFundingNeedsService: ReportFundingNeedsService) {}
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.reportFundingNeedsService
      .getFundingNeedsSummary()
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((response: any) => {
        // Parse the response and transform it into FundingNeeds array
        const fundingNeedsData: FundingNeeds[] = [];
        response.results.pdos.forEach(pdo => {
          pdo.pdo_advocacies.forEach(advocacy => {
            advocacy.pdo_programs.forEach(program => {
              fundingNeedsData.push({
                pdoName: pdo.name,
                pdoIdentifiedAdvocacy: advocacy.advocacy,
                program: program.program,
                yearProposed: program.proposed_date,
                unitOfItem: program.admin_beneficiary_category ? program.admin_beneficiary_category.category : '',
                location:
                  program.pdo_program_locations.length > 0 ? program.pdo_program_locations[0].location.name : '',
              });
            });
          });
        });

        // Assign the data array to MatTableDataSource
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<FundingNeeds>(fundingNeedsData);
      });
  }
}

Child template
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort (matSortChange)="announceSortChange($event)"
  class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns" [matColumnDef]="column.columnDef">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header sortActionDescription="Sort by {{ column.header }}">
      {{column.header}}
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      {{column.cell(row)}}
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>

Child ts
export class ReportsMatTableComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
  @Input() columns: {
    columnDef: string;
    header: string;
    cell: (element: any) => string;
  }[] = [];

  @Input() dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;

  displayedColumns: string[];

  constructor(private _liveAnnouncer: LiveAnnouncer) {}

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.columns) {
      this.displayedColumns = this.columns.map(c => c.columnDef);
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.dataSource);
    
    if (this.dataSource) {
      console.log("child has data");
      
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }
  }

  /** Announce the change in sort state for assistive technology. */
  announceSortChange(sortState: Sort) {
    // This example uses English messages. If your application supports
    // multiple language, you would internationalize these strings.
    // Furthermore, you can customize the message to add additional
    // details about the values being sorted.
    if (sortState.direction) {
      this._liveAnnouncer.announce(`Sorted ${sortState.direction}ending`);
    } else {
      this._liveAnnouncer.announce('Sorting cleared');
    }
  }
}


can you console response.results and fundingNeedsData in parent.ts to check it is not undefined.

yes it does contain FundingNeeds[] data, but some object.yearProposed is null

I change every null in fundingNeedsData to empty string, and it still won't display table rows

I noticed that on the parent component the table is populated with data when I click on something like <mat-select>.
So I thought that the issue is related to angular's change detection. Therefore I checked the child component, then the parent, then finally found the culprit in the layout component:
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-report-layout',
  templateUrl: './report-layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./report-layout.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class ReportLayoutComponent { }

After removing changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, my reusable component <app-reports-mat-table *ngIf="dataSource" [columns]="columns" [dataSource]="dataSource"></app-reports-mat-table> is now displaying table data.

I think that is a problem with "renderRows" like this SO
You can, in your child component make a setter -or perhafs using signal-
import {MatTable} from '@angular/material/table' //<--you need import MatTable

@ViewChild(MatTable, { static: true,read:MatTable }) table!:MatTable<any>

dataSource!:MatTableDataSource<any> //<--declare the variable
@Input('dataSource')  set _dataSource(value: MatTableDataSource<any>)
{
    this.dataSource=value;
    this.table.renderRows();
};

